# Mapping PAM-17 levels to PAM-5 levels

Tags: digital-communications, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, digital-to-analog

A $17$-level $\left\{ -4,-3.5,-3,\ldots,0, 0.5, 1,\ldots, 3.5, 4 \right\}$ digital signal coming at $125 \, \textrm{MHz}$ is passed through an FIR filter ($10$ taps) operating at $1250 \, \textrm{MHz}$ having coefficients as $ 0.25^{k}$ where $k = 1$ to $10$.

Comment: "that the output of the filter remains same" Sorry, I don't understand: *same* as *what*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller output of filter when 17-level signal is directly passed through the FIR filter and output when first the 17-level signals are passed through FIR filter and then passed through FIR filter should be same

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited the question as well. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe the FIR coefficients more clearly. What is $n$? Also, clarify the kind of oversampling you're doing. The example given makes no sense.

Comment: @MBaz edit the question. Let me know, if any more clarification you need!!

Answer (score 1):

> The mapping scheme should be such that output of the filter remains same for the case when directly 17-level signals are passed through FIR filter and when 17-level signals are first mapped to 4 level signal and then passed through FIR filter.

That's mathematically impossible (aside from the trivial case where everything gets filtered to 0):

Your filter an *injective system* for all but countable many frequencies. So, in general, two different inputs *must* have two different outputs.

The only exception hence are the zeros of the transfer function, but these don't help.

Now the situation looks different if instead of demanding that the "output of the filter" remains the same, that the result after synchronous downsampling is identical: that breaks the injectiveness of the operation.

A very trivial example then would be 17-fold sampling rate prior to downsampling. A simple choice of the alphabet $-0.5, 0, +0.5$ allows you to represent any of your 17 values if your filter is just a moving average.

However, it won't work with an even value for oversampling if you don't have 0 in your alphabet (can only achieve even summings that way); basic combinatorics.

Generally, it seems to me you're trying to re-invent the Delta-Sigma DAC. Well, don't! Just build a Delta-Sigma digital-to-digital converter, with a 2bit quantization each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Quantizing a 17-level signal to 4 levels loses information. Oversampling will not help you recover it, since the information content of `1` is the same as that of `1 1 1 1 1...`, no matter how many `1`s you use. So, what you're trying to do is impossible.